# Azure DevOps - Why I cannot show in a widget the total number of bugs created during an Iteration and group them by Iteration?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Hello I am using Azure DevOps - I would like to configure a Dashboard Widget to show in a the total number of bugs created during an Iteration and aggregated by Iteration?

I created a query to display the total number of bugs in the 2nd iteration . I added a chart of work items widged but in the Group by* I don't have iteration path option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the widget of `Chart for Work Items` in your project/team Dashboard of Azure DevOps, it appears a limitation at the moment that the widget can only calculate work items grouped by a set of columns (`Assigned to`, `State`, `Work Item Type` or `Tags`) rather than any column in your query results.

[image]

For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.